# Resize an SWT TableColumn so that all its data is visible

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a Dialog and a `TableViewer` inside it. Below is the code i used to construct the TableViewer:

```java
Composite tableComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
tableComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
tableComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,true));

TableViewer tableViewer = factory.buildTableViewer(tableComposite);
Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
table.setLinesVisible(true);
table.setHeaderVisible(true);

column1= new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
column1.getColumn().setText("Column1");
column1.getColumn().setResizable(false);

column2= new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
column2.getColumn().setText("Column2");
column2.getColumn().setResizable(false);

column3= new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
column3.getColumn().setText("Column3");
column3.getColumn().setResizable(false);

tableLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
tableComposite.setLayout(tableLayout);

layoutColumns();
```

Below is the code for layoutColumns() to set the table layout:

```
// Resize the columns to fit the contents
column1.getColumn().pack();
column2.getColumn().pack();
column3.getColumn().pack();

int column1Width = column1.getColumn().getWidth();
int column2Width = column2.getColumn().getWidth();
int column3Width = column3.getColumn().getWidth();

tableLayout.setColumnData(column1.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(0, rootObjFolderColumnWidth));
tableLayout.setColumnData(column2.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(0, column2));
tableLayout.setColumnData(column3.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(100, column3));
```

When I have large data in `column3`, I don't get to see the complete text, instead I get ... at the end. But I want the complete text to be seen with horizontal scrollbar.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH)); 
//and then on each of the TableViewerColumn 
column1.getColumn().pack();
```

This is as per [this link](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t82754.html) from eclipsezone forums